# Magento2 : Remove fields from Ui Component grid conditionally

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I want to remove **actionsColumn**, **massaction** and **status** fields of product grid if my custom configuration set to yes.

In magento 2 product grid is generated by `\vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\adminhtml\ui_component\product_listing.xml` how can I achieve this.

Comment: Override the Magento_catalog module

Comment: @Ramki how can i remove content of product_listing.xml conditionally even after rewriting?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if it is a right way to achieve this or not, I doesn't found any solution to achieve this. For now I am trying with following.

created one observer and check my condition if it satisfying the condition then I am redirecting to new url where I am creating new layout and grid by new ui component.